# How to merge different CSV file into a new CSV with one primary key

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have two huge CSV file and want them to join in one new CSV file with using python pandas, the primary key is id_student, it is ok that I successfully join different column together but when I output to a new CSV file, the whole bunch of data will only exist to the first row,  different column, for example, the row 1 column 1 will be id_student, it is like:

```
0  12345
1  12344
```

then row 1 column will be final_result, the format will like:

```
0  Pass
1  Pass
```

but my expected output will be like :

```
0  12345 Pass
1  12344 Pass
```

Is there any way I can fix the output format?

```py
def plotlyGraph(self):

    df = pandas.read_csv('studentAssessment.csv')
    dc = pandas.read_csv('studentInfo.csv')
    res = pandas.merge(df,dc, on=['id_student'], how='outer')
    a=res['id_student']
    b=res['final_result']
    c=res['score']
    d=res['id_assessment']
    e=res['region']

    with open("new.csv", "w", newline="") as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
        writer.writerow([a,b,c,d,e])
```

Comment: `res = df.merge(dc, on=['id_student'], how='outer')`

Comment: @Yusufsn Yeah I had tried that at the beginning and it still outputted the same format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming your `df` has 2 columns: `id_student` and `id_assessment`, while the `dc` has 2 columns: `id_student` and `final_result`. Try this one:

```
df = pandas.read_csv('studentAssessment.csv')
dc = pandas.read_csv('studentInfo.csv')

res = df.merge(dc, on=['id_student'], how='outer')
print(res)
```

Output

```
   id_student id_assessment final_result
0           0       12345          pass
1           1       12344          pass
```

To store in `csv` file:

```
res.to_csv("new.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: as I mentioned above, the CSV file contained huge data, for your code up there you just simply output a framework, how do I select the whole rows to merge? and also pandas doesnt read the csv file if you dont use pandas.read()